# Java: Splitting a String at two different points into 3 parts

Tags: java, regex, string, split

First post. Be nice?

Learning Java.

I have a String object `"1 Book on wombats at 12.99"`

I want to split this String into either a `String[]` OR an `ArrayList<String>` splitting the string on the first space and around the word " at " so my `String[]` has 3 Strings of `"1"` `"Book on wombats"` `"12.99"`

my current solution is:

```
// private method call from my constructor method
ArrayList<String> fields = extractFields(item);

  // private method
  private ArrayList<String> extractFields (String item) {
  ArrayList<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
  String[] sliceQuanity = item.split(" ", 2);
  parts.add(sliceQuanity[0]);
  String[] slicePrice = sliceQuanity[1].split(" at ");
  parts.add(slicePrice[0]);
  parts.add(slicePrice[1]);
  return parts;
  }
```

So this works fine, but surely there is a more elegant way? perhaps with regex which is something that I'm still trying to get a good handle on.

Thankyou!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing your code. Try asking it here, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: A single example is not enough information to write a pattern. There is no reasonable way to write a regex which works on actual data when you only provide a single example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your could use this pattern

```
^(\S+)\s(.*?)\sat\s(.*)$
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/80)

```
^        begining of string
(\S+)    caputre anything that is not a white space    
\s       a white space
(.*?)    capture as few as possible
\sat\s   followed by a white space, the word "at" and a white space
(.*)$    then capture anything to the end
```

Comment: for love of god, explain so we can learn?

Comment: did you use split function?

Comment: I used capturing groups

Comment: oh cool can you provide more info about it ? cuz when I use split function and put your regex inside it , it gives me the whole string. by the way, the other guy copied and pasted your answer

Comment: @KickButtowski, it is OK

Comment: @ifLoop, I like this format better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63972/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-alpha-bravo).

Answer (score 4):

This regex will return what you need: `^(\S+)\s(.*?)\sat\s(.*)$`

## Explanation:

`^` assert position at start of a line.

`\S+` will match any non-white space character.

`\s` will match any white space character.

`.*?` will match any character (except newline).

`\s` again will match any white space character.

`at` matches the characters `at` literally (case sensitive).

`\s` again will match any white space character.

`(.*)$` will match any character (except newline), and assert position at end of a line.

Answer (score 0):

Well it would be simpler by just calling .split() on item.
Store that array in a String[], then hardcode which index you want of your String[] into the ArrayList that you are returning. The String.concat() method might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code to arrive at the String[] result that you requested. Using the regex expression suggested in the other answers:

`^(\S+)\s(.*?)\sat\s(.*)$` is converted to a Java string by escaping each of the backslashes with another backslash, so they appear twice when creating the Pattern object.

```
String item = "1 Book on wombats at 12.99";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+)\\s(.*?)\\sat\\s(.*)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(item);
matcher.find();
String[] parts = new String[]{matcher.group(1),matcher.group(2),matcher.group(3)};
```

Comment: May also note this would throw a "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found" if your input string doesn't fit the pattern. Or you can inspect the return value of `mather.find()` to determine compatibility